# How to add Shadow to Triangle made with css `clip-path`?

Tags: css, clip-path

i have created A triangle with css `clip-path` property to have few content inside.

```
.triangle {
            background-color: grey;
            -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 10%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
            clip-path: polygon(50% 10%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            filter: drop-shadow(9px 9px 9px rgba(255, 23, 23, 0.5));


            img {
                width: 100%;
                position: relative;
                left: 0;
                top: 5%;

                @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
                    width: 110%;
                }
            }

            &::after {
                background-color: black;
                content: "";
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                transition: opacity .5s;
                opacity: 0;
            }
      }
```

i have put few content inside and for hover border effect i have created another triangle hidden back of this triangle.

I want to have SHADOW arround this triangle on hover. as shown in image given below.
[image]

I have tried `::before` but not working, and everyother solution avaialable is not working with clip-path triangle.

Comment: share full code including the HTML

Comment: I have tried to add code snippet but it was not working & code was not tidy and written in less.

Comment: Still Thank you for understanding and giving an alternate solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a parent element to `triangle` and add `drop-shadow` to the parent element.

Try this:

```css
.triangleParent {
  filter: drop-shadow(9px 9px 9px rgba(255, 23, 23, 0.5));
}

.triangle {
  background-color: grey;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 10%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 10%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  filter: drop-shadow(9px 9px 9px rgba(255, 23, 23, 0.5));
}

.triangle img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 5%;
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    width: 110%;
  }
}

.triangle::after {
  background-color: black;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangleParent">
  <div class="triangle">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding `filter: drop-shadow` to parent works like a charm. Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea without `clip-path` where the trick is to rely on cascading skew transformation to create the triangle shape and to keep the initial aspect of the content:

```css
.tri {
  margin: 40px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  border-left: 2px solid orange;
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: skewX(-32deg);
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 5px red);
}

.tri>.container {
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 2px solid orange;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: skewX(51.35deg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.tri>.container>div {
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: skewX(-32deg);
  height: 100%;
  
  /* Irrelevant styles */
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:center;
  color:#fff;
  background:
    linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.2)),
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/1000/800) center/cover;
}

body {
 background:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="tri">
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>some text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OH. This looks great. i'll for sure try it. i havent found this on internet before.
THANK YOU FOR THIS! :)